# T extends String as index of mapped type

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics, mapped-types

In my Project, I am using a mapped type (with `string`s as keys):

```js
export type ConfigurableFieldsType<T extends string[]> = {
  [field in keyof T]: string
}
```

In the following method, I am using the type (`this.configurableFields` is a `ConfigurableFieldsType` object):

```js
  private getConfigurableAttribute(attribute: C[number]): string {
    return this.configurableFields[attribute]
  }
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Type 'C[number]' cannot be used to index type 'ConfigurableFieldsType<C>'.
```

You can find the complete example (with reproducible error) in this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIgFXNAvFAzsATgSwHYDmUAPlHgK4C2ARhFgFD0QAeYA9lsFKJFAApY2AE3IBjYEkgAeBFBbAIeIegzZ8BANoBdAHxQ0Ab3pRYcAFynJEY9xzAANhAuZchGwEdyAQzzA7IZzU3EyEIdFFcMD82PEDXAhscSi8CMLj1bRtRGIAzHAJyLC9qRwAxHAh7ZQsAYVz8wuKyiqr0KxkdegBfRhZ2Tm5kKDq8PIKikohyyuV22XlFZVV47T1DGw08mah8KABrCBA2HKgELXS3HqZWDi5Rey90FQFhMWApGDlmBSUVeCsADTDL4-JYuDK6HaUMCOSiKYDPQQicTtGp6IwmbJ4FxvDgAChsJjA5BKOFEpgsMABhKgxNJ5L8Dicy3U1JMRJJ9jJUE8PkZARZhDZ7LpXPJoXCkWisUFBGFHPpUJSaVl2nltM53KxY0ak2mrVq9XGTSmLVmyCkaOFAEooAYrkTcAA3LwKKCpYAjHUTRwAQWAamo5AUeNdgeDzJqGgoNDoWmtFyIGPZWAgwEKeG4AAscOgAHTaho+00zdAaMO4IMKLQ2Ho9IA) or in the following:

```js
export type ProductType<T extends string[]> = {
  // more variables
  configurableFields: ConfigurableFieldsType<T>
}

export type ConfigurableFieldsType<T extends string[]> = {
  [field in keyof T]: string
}

export class Product<C extends string[]> implements ProductType<C> {
  constructor(
    // more public parameters
    public configurableFields: ConfigurableFieldsType<C>,
  ) {}

  private getConfigurableAttribute(attribute: C[number]): string {
    return this.configurableFields[attribute]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full [mre] as plain text in the body of the post.  The Playground link is a nice supplement but we cannot require that people leave Stack Overflow in order to see the full question.

Comment: In your definition of `ConfigurableFieldsType`, `keyof T` is going to be array keys like `push` and `pop` and `0` and `1`, etc.  If you want the keys to be the strings in the `T` array you want `T[number]` and not `keyof T`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Woa99N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Do note that in a mapped type of the form `{[K in X]: Y}`, `K` is a keylike *type parameter*, not a key *name*.  Using `field` as in `{[field in X]: Y}` is thus unconventional naming.  Consider changing to something like `K` or possibly `Field` (although the usual convention is single uppercase letters for type parameters).

Comment: @jcalz That is exactly it, thank you very much. I'll mark your answer as accepted as soon as it is written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You intend `ConfigurableFieldsType<["a", "b", c"]>` to evaluate to something like `{a: string, b: string, c: string}`, but your current definition would result in `[string, string, string]`.  That's because `{[K in keyof T]: string}` results in a [mapped array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays); `T` is an arraylike type, and `keyof T` is thus the array keys, like `"push"` or `"length"`.

Instead, you want the keys of your type to be *elements* of `T`.  That is, the types you get when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T` with a numeric index... so instead of `keyof T`, you want `T[number]`:

```
export type ConfigurableFieldsType<T extends string[]> = {
  [K in T[number]]: string
}

type Example = ConfigurableFieldsType<["a", "b", "c"]>
/* type Example = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
} */
```

And now things work as you intend:

```
private getConfigurableAttribute(attribute: C[number]): string {
  return this.configurableFields[attribute] // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgIgFXNAvFAzsATgSwHYDmUAPlHgK4C2ARhFgFD0QAeYA9lsFKJFAApY2AE3IBjYEkgAeBFBbAIeIegzZ8BANoBdAHxQ0Ab3pRYcAFynJEY9xzAANhAuZchGwEdyAQzzA7IZzU3EyEIdFFcMD82PEDXAhscSi8CMLj1bRtRGIAzHAJyLC9qRwAxHAh7ZQsAYVz8wuKyiqr0KxkdegBfRhZ2Tm5kKDq8PIKikohyyuV22XlFZVV47T1DGw0AaSh8KAQNCho6LS10tx76HmgAUWYvSjBHfWH68aapltnkKQ0AIi9fgAaKC-ahAkGiX66egAegAVINeLd7o9UFAjCYTF4zgQANw2EzUHH4zFQUTE7pQOEw3qsDhcUT2LzoFQCYRiYBSGByZgKJQqeBWYE1Hl8pYuDK6HYPRyURTAVmCETido1PQYskxFwcjgACgJUDA5BKOFEpgsMEBBqNJrNfgcTmW6itpJt9lNUE8PntASdhBdmLdHtC4Ui0VifoIAZMQbNSRSaUj2mjhuN7rN2VGDQmzRm6Fqr0ak2mrVVOgDAEp0VALjHcAA3LwKKCpYAjMZFxwAQWAamo5AUuqbfYHjpqByotCwWgrOPRBqwEGAhTw3AAFjh0AA6TMdnMfPMaYe4fsKLRQGEwqBsADWXhANh6PSAA)